# CoRS supporting schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

I am trying to retrieve informations from server using

```
function retrieveShops( id ){
    get('localhost:8080/shops/' + id).then(function(res){
        alert(res)
    })
}

function get(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    req.send();
  });
}
```

and on the server i am capturing it

```
app.get('/shops:id' , function( req , res ){
  var id = req.params.id;
   db.shop.findOne({
      where:{
        componentId: id
      }
   }).then(function(u){
    res.send(u)
   })
})
```

However the chrome return

> shops_showcase.js:34 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   localhost:8080/shops/1. Cross origin requests are only supported for
>   protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https,
>   chrome-extension-resource.

this error.

I tried to allow CORS using

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

But the error still remains. What is the way to allow cors or how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you change your `get()` function to `get('http://localhost:8080/shops/' + id)` ?

Comment: ^ At least someone reads the actual error message

Comment: Agreed with Alex. I expect this is just a protocol requirement on the url provided to the Ajax request from the client side.